# Merge two word documents with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an excel table IN the word document with some data like

[image]

(don't mind the russian symbols)

And i need to merge that with another word document which is a letter (i.e. replace the "First and Last name" with an actual First and Last name. But i only need to choose those people, who have value more than 220 in penultimate column (on the picture)
As far as i know this code is only applicable with excel document:

```
MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
Name:=""
```

That's why i cant use this SQL-statement:

```
SELECT * FROM 'Лист1$'WHERE'...'>=220 And '...'='...'
```

How can i merge those 2 word documents?

Comment: In general, you can use the SQLStatement parameter with Excel data sources, but you may need to change your SQL statement a little. Excel will probably recognise [ ] around table names etc.or backquotes, but probably not straight single quotes ' '. (e.g. the following is more likely to work: MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:="the path and name of the Excel workbook", SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM ['Лист1$] WHERE [...] >= 220 And [...] = '...'"

Comment: It's not possible for Word to use an Excel table embedded in another document as a data source for a mail merge. Is there a reason you can't copy the table and paste it into another Word document, using that as a data source?